# Unity3D WWW get HTML displayed in browser

Tags: javascript, web, unity-game-engine

I currently have in a web page, on a localhost server, some information that I want to use in Unity. My problem is that this information are stored in some js variables.

I tried to use the WWW class in a coroutine, but I only get the html source code. Is there a way to get the value of this variables inside Unity Editor ?

Thanks !

Comment: I'm sure that Stack Overflow is more than capable of helping with this, but you might have a more targeted audience if you ask on [Game Dev Stack Exchange](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I don't have much experience on game dev, I didn't know this website. Thanks !